# My website using Vite PWA sending 100+ workbox initiated requests for small js scripts when the site is upgraded to a newer version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, vite, workbox

I just migrated a react route-based code-splitting site to Vite.js with its PWA plugin. After upgrading the production site to the latest version, I reloaded the page in Chrome and found that the workbox sending 100+ requests for js scripts in the background. I recognized the scripts as their names come from my react component files. This fetching only happens every time the site is upgraded and the service worker is updated and its cache is cleared:

[image]

[image]

I checked the responses of the js scripts and they were all redirected to the index.html files.

It seems that it only happens in Chrome. Firebox doesn't have any issues.

```
export default defineConfig(async () => {
  return {
    plugins: [
      importToCDN(),
      VitePWA({
        base: "/",
        registerType: "prompt",
        manifest: {
          name: "xxx",
          short_name: "xxx",
          icons: xxx,
          display: "standalone",
          start_url: `xxx`,
          orientation: "portrait",
        },
      }),
      react({
        babel: {
          parserOpts: {
            plugins: ["decorators-legacy", "classProperties"],
          },
        },
        include: "**/*.{jsx,tsx}",
      }),
      viteS3(),
    ],
  };
});
```

React Route Code Splitting Example:

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from ‘react’;
import ReactDOM from ‘react-dom’;

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: (
       <React.Suspense>
           <Outlet />
       </React.Suspense>
    ),
    children: [
     {
        path: "/home",
        lazy: () => import("./pages/home"),
     },
     {
        path: "/about",
        lazy: () => import("./pages/about"),
     }
    ],
  },
]);


const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("container")); // createRoot(container!) if you use TypeScript
root.render(
    <RouterProvider router={router} />

);
```

Is it normal for the workbox/service worker to send so many requests like this every time a newer version of the site is launched?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you're observing is normal with Workbox and Service Workers for sites with route-based code splitting. Each JavaScript chunk generated by Vite.js is treated as a separate resource by the Service Worker, and Workbox attempts to cache each of these chunks separately.

The redirection to index.html might be due to your server or Vite.js configuration, which might be set up to serve index.html as a fallback for missing files.

Browser differences could stem from how Chrome and Firefox handle Service Workers and caching.

If this behavior is problematic for your use case, you could consider adjusting your Workbox and Service Worker configuration to alter caching strategies or exclude certain chunks from being pre-cached.

Comment: Yes, I just found that the files listed in 'sw.js' all point to my server public folder but they are actually uploaded to a s3 buckle mapped to a Cloudflare subdomain, so workbox probably keeps fetching these missing files repeatedly which results in making so many requests. Now I need to find out how to make sw.js precache files on cdn, maybe this thread should help: https://github.com/vite-pwa/vite-plugin-pwa/issues/343 . Will try this 'manifestTransforms' option later.

Comment: I just used `workbox.modifyURLPrefix` to make sw.js pre-cache assets from cdn!